# Why are duplicate dependencies in dependencyManagement not inherited?

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management

If I add a duplicate `dependency` in `dependencyManagement`, which is already managed in parent pom, dependency management only considers this last declaration, anything declared in parent is ignored.

Are there any use-cases not inherit parent `dependencyManagement`?

In my hypothetical example I have `org.jooq:jooq:3.16.9` which depends on `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:0.9.0.RELEASE`.
Parent POM declares a **newer** version `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:0.9.1.RELEASE`. If Child POMs would use jooq they would get `0.9.1.RELEASE` of `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi`. This is an [expected behavior](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). So far so good.

If now a Child POM decides to change only the `scope` and does not provide a version, Maven resolves the version of `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi` to `0.9.0.RELEASE`, which is declared by `org.jooq:jooq:3.16.9`.
(Same behavior with `scope` and `exclusions`, even when I import parent instead of inheriting.)

I expected, that Maven would resolve `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi` to `0.9.1.RELEASE` since it is declared in parent `dependencyManagement`.

Duplicate dependencies in `dependencyManagement` are [re-declared and not inherited](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-management):

> Finally, since d is specified in B's dependency management section, should d be a dependency (or transitive dependency) of a or c, version 1.0 will be chosen - again because dependency management takes precedence over dependency mediation and also because the current POM's declaration takes precedence over its parent's declaration.

### POMs

(Actual artifacts are only used for illustration purpose, there might have been other better artifacts ...)

**Parent POM**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenParentTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>r2dbc-spi</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
                <version>3.16.9</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version> <!-- just to fix plugins version -->
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Child POM**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>MavenChildTest</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>MavenParentTest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>r2dbc-spi</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Running: `mvn dependency:tree -f child/pom.xml` leads to following output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:tree (default-cli) @ MavenChildTest ---
[INFO] org.example:MavenChildTest:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.jooq:jooq:jar:3.16.9:compile
[INFO]    +- io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:jar:0.9.0.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:runtime
[INFO]    \- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]       \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:2.0.0:compile
```

Comment: There are [Tests for missing groupId or artifactId](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/03df5f7c639db744a3597c7175c92c8e2a27767b/maven-model-builder/src/test/java/org/apache/maven/model/validation/DefaultModelValidatorTest.java#L254-L265) but not for version. Even thought there is [an example for this](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/03df5f7c639db744a3597c7175c92c8e2a27767b/maven-model-builder/src/test/resources/poms/validation/missing-dependency-mgmt-version-pom.xml).